# Is something known about the third term in Weyl law?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

The well-known Weyl law states that if $\Omega$ is a open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ that is "nice enough" (I don't want to enter into details on this point) and if $N(\lambda)$ is the number of eigenvalues of the laplacian operator on $\Omega$ with Dirichlet condition on $\partial \Omega$ that are less or equal to $\lambda$, then
$$N(\lambda)= (2\pi)^{-d}\lambda ^{d/2} \omega_d \mathrm{vol} (\Omega)- \frac{1}{4} (2\pi)^{1-d}\omega_{d - 1}\lambda ^{(d-1)/2}\mathrm{area} (\partial \Omega) +o (\lambda^{(d-1)/2})$$
where $\omega_{d}$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^d$.

I wonder if anything is known about the third term of the asymptotics. Even for specific cases (rectangles or disks in $\mathbb R^2$, rectangular cuboids or balls in $\mathbb R^3$, etc.), I can't find any information on that...

Does anyone have any information on this problem ?

**EDIT:** to be clearer, I am talking about a third term in asymptotics:
$$ N(\lambda)= (2\pi)^{-d}\lambda ^{d/2} \omega_d \mathrm{vol} (\Omega)- \frac{1}{4} (2\pi)^{1-d}\omega_{d - 1}\lambda ^{(d-1)/2}\mathrm{area} (\partial \Omega) + F(\lambda) + \mathrm{remainder\ term}$$
Is something know about $F(\lambda)$, even in special cases ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Sorry but I don't understand your answer. I am already aware of this article and its results. They talk about the remainder term $o(\lambda^{(d-1)/2})$, not about a third term in the asymptotics.

Comment: It's possible to compute the spectrum of a rectangle or an equilateral triangle explicitly. It's also possible to compute the spectrum of a disk in terms of the roots of Bessel functions. In those special cases it should be possible to understand the higher order asymptotics, so that might be a good place to start.

Comment: For a square, this is essentially the Gauss circle problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem The result quoted there seems to give $F=O(\lambda^a)$, $a\simeq 0.32$, and if the conjecture mentioned there is true, then $a=1/4+\epsilon$.